# Deriving the optimum value of a function

Tags: optimization, convergence

I have a function $f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} |y_i-t|$.

What will be the optimum value of t that will minimize it. How to derive it?

Similarly what is the optimal value of t which minimizes $f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} |y_i-t|^{\infty}$?

Comment: You might like to draw a plot of f vs t first, to see what's going on, though for the second one you'll have to look at it as a process approaching a limit.

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Comment: Note that CV is NOT a 'do my homework' site. Please add the self-study tag, and read its tag wiki info to what your responsibilities include.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some major hints to get you started:

For the first one, you might want to consider what $f'$ looks like (as a formula) between the sorted data values (it's discontinuous at the data values). How does it behave as you move through the data? Where does it change from below 0 to above 0?

Here's $f$ vs $t$ (the grey vertical bars on top of the x-axis are the data values):

[image]

Can you see how to show what will minimize $f$ now?

---

For the second case, consider $f_k(t) = ( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |y_i-t|^{k} )^{1/k}$ (you would need to argue that $f_k$ and $f$ share an argmin for a given $k$ - that is taking the $1/k$ power doesn't change the location of the minimum. Below (for the same data as above) $f_k$ is plotted for $k = 2,3,5,9,$ and $99$ (the "$k=2$" case is faint dotted grey at the top, the "$k=99$" case is purple near the bottom):

[image]

The "$k=2$" case corresponds to least squares, while $k=1$ would be the previous example. As $k$ increases, it's getting 'pointier'. Can you figure where the 'point' is headed, and why? Can you work out $f_k'$? What happens to that as $k$ increases?

Comment: Yeah, I could see that it is the median. But I am not being able to prove it

Comment: Did you do what I suggested with the derivative? What does it give you?

Comment: I got the derivative something like this $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-\frac{y_i-t}{|y_i-t|})$. I can't equate it to zero

Comment: Also for the second question it is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}({|y_i-t|^{\infty}})$ not what you have written

Comment: (i) *you don't equate it to zero*, as I already explained. (ii) I discussed the difference in my answer. I suggest you think carefully about what I wrote, and answer every question I have asked, in comments or in my answer that has not already been responded to.  You don't seem to be putting much thought into working with what information you've already been given.

Comment: The answer is given by minimum subgradient the one with the least slope which is at the median

Comment: The answer is given by minimum subgradient the one with the least slope which is at the median

Comment: Think about simplifying $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-\frac{y_i-t}{|y_i-t|})$, (hint: what is $\text{sign}(x)|x|$?) and look again at the plot and my discussion. The slope is actually undefined at the median.

Comment: The answer is when it is at minimum subgradient which is the median point at the point where sign(x)|x| changes sign

Comment: Wrong both times, I'm afraid. Forget about your problem and actually *evaluate*  sign(x)|x| for various values of $x$. Then explain how to simplify your $f'$ equation from a few comments up. Then draw it for a small sample.

Comment: The gradient is given by sign(x)|x| itself which is undefined at the points where t= the given points.

Comment: Like I said, **actually evaluate sign(x)|x| for various values of x**. What do you notice about sign(x)|x|? Hence, what is x/|x|?